# FetchError: Error fetching https://r.stripe.com/0:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have implemented stripe payment method in my react website as per [this](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react) documentation

Now everything is working fine but console giving the error (shown in below image) and because of this error my payments shows status "incomplete" on stripe website's payment dashboard

[image]

Error is : (in promise) FetchError: Error fetching https://r.stripe.com/0:

Comment: The URL `r.stripe.com` is flagged as "unsafe" by your adblocker

Answer (score 1):

`r.stripe.com` is a URL that stripe.js uses for telemetry. These errors should not affect your page's functionality but if they do definitely write in to https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

Stripe tries to detect and fix when stripe.js is throwing these errors so as to avoid polluting your developer console.